# What is this word in 19th century dictionary?

Tags: terminology, dictionaries, science, books

I was reading a passage from P. Austin Nuttall's 1869 book, [*Dictionary of Scientific Terms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lIYDAAAAQAAJ&lpg=SL26-PA62&ots=SKp9h7ZOzX&dq=Pseudostetla&pg=SL26-PA62#v=onepage&q=pseudostetla&f=false), and from what it looks like, in both the *PDF* and *Page images* views, the word seems to be *pseudostella*.

However, I looked up the word online, in the OED, ODO, M-W, Dictionary.com, Wikipedia, Google, and Encyclopædia Britannica, and I couldn't find anything. So, I checked out the *Plain text* view, and it showed the spelling is *pseudosteTla*. But this made no sense to me (it still doesn't). So I thought maybe it's a text-rendering issue on Google's part. But, again, I don't know.

Anybody have an idea what it is?

*PDF* View

[image: 1]

*Page images* View

[image: 2]

*Plain text* View

[image: 3]

Comment: yeah, it's an optical scanning issue. It's clearly *pseudostella* (*pseudo-* means "fake" and *stella* means "star".) Googling it reveals it to be the name of a [moth genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudostella), and it is also defined the way you describe on [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pseudostella). I'm a bit confused why you has trouble finding it in other dictionaries – apparently it's fairly rare.

Comment: OCR has mistaken the first "l" followed by the acute stress accent for a "T".

Comment: It has certainly not reached the OED but they would probably be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: @sumelic: I'm confused. In my understanding, StackExchange is not an encyclopedia; thus, it doesn't have to have usefulness for all viewers. It's a support site, where people ask questions they want to understand or know the answer to in order to understand something or learn more about something. The "interesting/useful answer" is the one that tells me what it means and solves the issue I described here. -_-

Comment: @sumelic: Also, there are plenty of people here who would probably find a post like this interesting, FYI.

Comment: @sumelic: That **is** the solution to my issue. I didn't know it was an OCR error; I thought it was a word I had never heard of.

Comment: Exactly, which was part of the reason why I was confused. It was multiple issues wrapped into one: 1) It looked like *pseudostella* to me, which was a word I didn't know; 2) The plaintext showed it as *pseudosteTla*, and I didn't know it was an OCR error, thus I thought it was a word; and 3) *pseudosteTla* would have been a word I didn't know, in which I still would've wanted to know what it meant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on an OCR error that has now been explained. There is nothing more to be said or learned bout this question.

Comment: @SvenYargs: What is the difference between marking a question as `closed` as opposed to `solved`?

Comment: "Solved" isn't an option for answers on this site. "Accepted" (which is up to the questioner to indicate) means that the questioner is satisfied that the answer so designated has resolved the question—at least that's how I understand it. "Closed" means that the question is no longer open to further answers and may or may not be deleted (removed from the site) at some future date by moderators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is "pseudostella", from Greek *ψεύδος*/*pseudos* "false" + Latin *stella* "star". I've never seen it used before but it's a fairly standard combination of roots. The capital 'T' is an error on the part of the OCR system: it's taking the stress marker as part of the letter.

Comment: @sumelic I generally use the traditional Roman transcription for things like this, as it's traditional when Greek roots are borrowed into English words. But 'eu' for ευ creates an ambiguity in the ending -eus (which could be -ευς as in "basileus" or -εος as in verbal adjectives). I agree it looks weird here; I'll adjust that.

Comment: That's a good point about the ambiguity (though aren't other digraphs equally ambiguous?). Also, it looks like Josh has a citation from Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary that uses the same convention you do.

Comment: @sumelic Not to the same extent in my experience. υι is rare, ου becomes 'ū', and neither αυς nor αος is a particularly common noun ending. But mostly I just leave those because 'ay' looks so wrong. :P

And that's interesting with the Webster's, I hadn't looked at their transcription method before. I'll have to do that. (Also to see how they resolve η vs ει vs ῑ vs rough breathing, since I haven't yet found a system that keeps all of those distinct.)

Answer (score 0):

The term appears to be quite rare, but can be found in a few dictionaries; the accent between the two (l'l) is to stress the pronunciation of a double consonant. The term "stella" is still current usage in Italian and the *double l* requires a little longer sound. The *Tl* transcription looks like an error.

> - Pseudostella (Astron) Any starlike meteor or phenomenon.

Etymology:

> - NL., fr. Gr. pseydh`s false + L. stella, star

(Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the accent has nothing to do with a double consonant sound (which doesn't exist in English), but is to mark the position of the stress on the second-to-last syllable.

Comment: Yes, but the pronunciation is the Latin one.

Comment: No; the image in the OP's question is from an English dictionary of scientific terms that marks English pronunciations.

Comment: So why put the accent between the two consonants?

Comment: Probably it's related to the convention of placing a hyphen between two identical consonants.

Comment: Probably, just your guess. The Latin pronunciation is quite clear.

Comment: There's **no way** that dictionary is using the acute to mark the Latin pronunciation. Just take a look inside; there are plenty of terms not from Latin, and other terms where the stress is different in English and Latin. I can't find a place where it lays out the exact rules it uses, but the acute is used in other English dictionaries like this.

Comment: Yes but this is a double consonant case, I don't see why as a scientific term it could not retain the Latin pronunciation.

Comment: @sumelic - 

Pronunciation: 
***IPA(key): /ˈstel.la/, [ˈs̪t̪el̺.l̺a]*** https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/stella#Etymology_2 - ***Stella***: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Stella

Comment: The pronunciation in Italian is irrelevant. Nobody but you is talking about Italian.

Comment: It is ***Latin*** that can be found in Etymonline.

Comment: Nobody disputes that the word *originates* in Latin either. The only part of your answer that I object to is the false statement that the acute in the *English* dictionary entry indicates a phonetically doubled consonant, when it actually indicates that the preceding syllable is stressed in English (as [deadrat](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282016/what-is-this-word-in-19th-century-dictionary/282026?noredirect=1#comment625943_282016) notes).

Comment: Please provide evidence to what you are saying, I've provided mine.

Comment: Look at other entries in the dictionary linked in the original post. In many places, the accent is used between two *different* consonants. In those places, it is therefore *impossible* that it is being used "to stress the pronunciation of a double consonant." It always appears directly after the stressed syllable. Example: [Colum´bidae](https://books.google.com/books?id=lIYDAAAAQAAJ&lpg=SL26-PA62&ots=SKp9h7ZOzX&dq=Pseudostetla&pg=SL26-PA62#v=snippet&q=columba&f=false)...

Comment: ...which as you can see from the [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/columbidae) entry is stressed on the second syllable.

Comment: (Sorry if that link doesn't work for you; you can find it through Google at least "merriam webster columbidae" .)

Comment: Lastly, there are words where the accent *is* used between two identical consonants, but other dictionaries show that there is no doubling of the consonant sound. Examples: [Cel´lular and Cel´lulose](https://books.google.com/books?id=lIYDAAAAQAAJ&lpg=SL26-PA62&ots=SKp9h7ZOzX&dq=Pseudostetla&pg=SL26-PA62#v=onepage&q=cella&f=false), which are pronounced [/ˈseljələ(r)/](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cellular?q=cellular) and [/ˈseljuləʊs/](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cellulose?q=cellulose).